# In pure CSS or JS (Jquery) change style of a parent but only on hover of one specific sub child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, submenu

I am using Wordpress and Elementor to build a mega menu.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see on the attached screenshot, I would like to change the header border-bottom-left and right radius to 0 when I hover items on my menu who have sub items.

Below you will find a simplified modeling of the present code (there is a lot more div between each elements as I use a CMS).

```
<section class="header">
   <div class="logo">...</div>
   <div class="menu">...</div>
      <ul>
         <li class="menu-item">Item 1</li>
         <li class="menu-item">Item 2</li>
         <li class="menu-item">Item 3</li>
         <li class="menu-item has-children">Item 4</li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div>Content of my submenu</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
      <ul>
   <div class="buttons">...</div>
</section>
```

What I would like is : when I hover the `<li>` with the class "has-children" to change the style of the parent `<section>` with the class "header", in order to modify his border radius bottom left and right.

I would love any idea to help me doing it in pure CSS or with a bit of JS.

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `:has()` selector so you can determine if one of the grandchildren elements is hovered. Added some basic CSS to get the basic idea down, you just need the  `section:has()` lines

```css
ul ul {
  display: none;
}

section.header {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}

ul>li.has-children:hover ul {
  display: block;
}


/* what you want to use */

section:has(li.has-children:hover) {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <div class="logo">...</div>
  <div class="menu">...</div>
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="menu-item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="menu-item">Item 3</li>
    <li class="menu-item has-children">Item 4
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>Content of my submenu</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="buttons">...</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Should be mentioned that Firefox still only supports `:has()` behind a flag though, so this will not work for "normal" users of that browser.

Comment: So one could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports_static and determine if not supported and add JavaScript to toggle a class.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working, at least, on Chrome. In order to take zero risks I used some JS to toggle a class as mentionned by @epascarello.

Answer (score -3):

What you need is to add the following code to your CSS

```
.has-children:hover section {apply any css here}
```

or

```
.has-children:hover .header {apply any css here}
```

With that code, every time you hover any has-children, the css in header/section will change to anything you want.

For example:

```
.has-children:hover .header {background:red}
```

This will change the background color of section / header to red when you hover the LI has children.

Is that what you need? It was a little difficult to understand the question. But if you want to ask me something else just ask me here

Comment: Doubt this is what the OP wanted. How is this going to target the section element?

Comment: Hi, thanks but it can not work that way, .has-children is a child element of .header so I can not use a CSS declaration in the order your used.